# Call controller which returns view in javascript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working in ASP.Net MVC. I have following Javascript code in which i am calling a controller-method which returns a view. I want to send parameters to a controller method which re

```
function fun(p1,p2)
        {
          // code here to call controller method which returns view   
        }



public ActionResult ProblemDetails(p1,p2)
        {
           // here goes some code.
             return View();
}
```

Please tell me the code which can be used to call controller and send parameters too.

Comment: Navigate to that URL?

Answer (score 2):

### **Action Method**

```
public ActionResult SendStream(string a, string b)
{

}
```

### **JQuery/JSON**

Please note that `Get Verb` will not support complex Data parameters due to it's `Query string` length constraint. So use `POST Verb` instead of `GET Verb` while sending large data

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify({ a: "a", b: "b" }), //Two String Parameters
    type: 'GET',                              //For Submit, use POST
    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
    //Success Callback
}).fail(function (data) {
    //Failed Callback        
}).always(function(data) { 
    //Request completed Callback
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.
For example Ajax:

Quick note first: Make sure that in your MVC routing configuration you have a route configured to reflect the following url below:

```
function fun(p1,p2)
{
     var url = '/ControllerName/ProblemDetails?p1=p1&p2=p2' //url to your action method

    $.ajax({
       url:url,
       type:'post' or 'get', //(depending on how you're doing this. If post you can pass data internally instead of query string ),
       dataType:'html', //(for example)
       success:function(data){
            //data here will contain your View info so you can append it do div for example. You can use JQuery .html() function for that
       error: function (xhr) {
        //catch error
         } 
        }
    })
}
```

Another way, in case if you want to load your View data to DIV is to use JQUery functions such as .load();

```
function fun(p1,p2)
{
     var url = '/ControllerName/ProblemDetails?p1=p1&p2=p2';

     $('#YourDivTagForExample').load(url);
 }
```

`$.ajax` call can also be abbriviated to `$.get`, `$.post` or `$.getJSON` depending on what kind of a call you want to make to your action method. There is a lot more to it too.

Finally make sure to take a look at this answer. Your question was actually already answered in full:
[Correct way to handle Ajax calls in ASP.Net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098349/correct-way-to-handle-ajax-calls-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking to return a Partial View? You can use jQuery ajax to post to a controller method that returns a Partial View (html). You can then render that HTML on the page.

http://mazharkaunain.blogspot.com/2011/04/aspnet-mvc-render-partial-view-using.html

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is the shorthand way to achieve this.

```
function fun(p1,p2)
{
    var url = '/controller/ProblemDetails?p1=' + p1 + '&p2=' + p2;
    $.get(url, function (data) {
      // data will be your response as html
    });
}
```

I might also suggest to have the action return PartialView() instead of View() since you will not return the layout along with the response. It all depends on your intentions for the returned html.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONResult instead of ActionResult and Manipulate return data in javascript.